# Understanding two pointer technique for nth last in linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to understand the following implementation for returning the nth last node in a linked list:

```
const nthLastNode = (linkedList, n) => {
  let current = null;
  let tailSeeker = linkedList.head;
  let count = 0;
  while (tailSeeker) {
    tailSeeker = tailSeeker.next;
    if (count >= n) {
      if (!current) {
        current = linkedList.head;
      }
      current = current.next;
    }
    count++
  }
  return current;
}
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding the flow of this method. `tailSeeker` will move through the entire list until it reaches a null value and `current` will follow behind it. I don't understand how the `count` comparisons with `n` and increments is useful. if you're looking for the 9th last node in a list of 10, that would be the second node, so why is it helpful to compare a count initialized at 0 and incrementing by 1 each step to the value of 9? Once you moved one step you're already at the right node and ``count``` will be 1, so why compare it to 9?
What am I missing here??

Comment: you don't know beforehand until you reach the end.

Comment: `count` isn't mean to index the `current` element (i.e. the "second" node at `count=1`), but it is the index of the  `tailSeeker` node. The comparison with `n` is so that  `current` follows behind by exactly `n` elements - it stays `null` for the first `n-1` elements, then follows behind by advancing in lockstep.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, that clears it up for me!